# PHP - Zend3, Jquery, Ajax (post)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework3

I have built a website using php and the zend framework. In one of the pages I have a zend form and a table. The user can fill in the form, click the search button(page refresh occurs) and then get the corresponding results in the table.

What I am trying to do is to implement the same functionality using Ajax so the page won't have to refresh or ask for re-submission when reloaded.

From my controller I pass the data I want to display to view.phtml.
When the page first opens all the data from database gets displayed in the table. Somehow after the user clicks search :

- the ajax post data should be retrieved in the controller
- compared to the rest of the data to see if there are any matches
- return the data matched

  ```
  public function searchAction(): ViewModel
  {
      $persons = $this->personsService->getAllPersons();
      $form = $this->personsForm;
  ```

  `if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
      $formData = $this->params()->fromPost();
      $form->setData($formData);

      if ($form->isValid()) {
          $validFilteredData = $form->getData();
          $persons = $this->personsService->getPersonsAfterSearch($validFilteredData);
      }
  }

  return new ViewModel([
      'persons' => $persons,
      'form' => $form,
  ]);
  }`

I would like any suggestions on how to implement ajax since I am a beginner in web development and I don't experience working with ajax.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this:

```
return new ViewModel([
    'persons' => $persons,
    'form' => $form,
]);
```

Add this:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel(
        [
            'persons' => $persons,
            'form'    => $form,
        ]
    );
}
```

---

Note: you've tagged "zend-framework" but mentioned "zend3". Above solution works for ZF2 and ZF3, don't know about ZF1.

---

#### Update due to comments:

Full function would be:

```
public function searchAction() : ViewModel
{
    $persons = $this->personsService->getAllPersons();
    $form = $this->personsForm;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->params()->fromPost();
        $form->setData($formData);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $validFilteredData = $form->getData();
            $persons = $this->personsService->getPersonsAfterSearch($validFilteredData);
        }
    }

    $data = [
        'persons' => $persons,
        'form'    => $form,
    ];

    // AJAX response
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel($data);
    }

    return $data; // No need to return "new ViewModel", handled via ZF magic
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I currently have is a Zend form which after submitting I retrieve the data using if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()). I can not retrieve the using if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) because it is not an ajax post I suppose. This is what I am trying to find out, how to send the data from phtml as ajax post

Comment: That's what this does. Add it before the return (response). The rest of the function remains untouched. I'll add a quick update